# Vue CLI - plugin vue-chartjs does not install

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-cli

I use Vue CLI for my project and I'm going to use the `vue-chartjs` plugin.

I used this guide for installation: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#installation but I got this error from `npm`:

[image: Error content]

Comment: As suggested by the error, did you tried to run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`? Otherwise, you will need to find the matching versions for each package.

Comment: isn't it like `--force` ? I know the `--force` might destroy stability.

Comment: Never really used `force` myself but I don't think that it's the same. Also, if it's peerDeps, that should not be an issue regarding the stability. But at the same time, I'm usually using yarn and have no issues at all.

Comment: I used peerDeps and worked. do you say yarn is better than npm?

Comment: I think that the best is PNPM, then yarn, then NPM. Personal preference and less issues + more features for me personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP fixed the issue by using `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`.